# MySQL, SELECT de acordo com a especialização da ocorrência da entidade genérica

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Na minha base de dados eu tenho uma entidade genérica "user", tal entidade é especializada em duas outras "store" e "service_provider", essa especialização tem característica total e exclusiva, de forma que, uma ocorrência de "user" deve estar a associada a no mínimo uma entidade especializada e somente de um tipo "store" ou "service_provider".[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo "type" referencia a qual especialização a ocorrência de "User" pertence, sendo type = '1'(store) e type='2'(service_provider).

Veja que a tabela "store" tem o campo "company_name" que diz qual o nome da empresa e a tabela "service_provider" tem o "name" referente ao nome da pessoa física.

**DÚVIDA**: em uma *query*, é possivel eu coletar os valores de uma ocorrência de "user", verificar a qual especialização essa ocorrência pertence (pelo campo "type"), sendo que se for um "store" dar um JOIN com o campo "company_name" ou "name" caso for um "service_provider"?.

Eu pensei dessa forma (pseudo código):

```
 SELECIONAR LINHA DE user ONDE id_user = ?

 INNER JOIN

 IF ((SELECIONAR type DE user ONDE id_user = ? ) = '1',
    SELECIONAR company_name DE store ONDE id_user = ?,
    SELECIONAR name DE service_provider ONDE id_user = ?
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível, e existem algumas abordagens que pode variar conforme o seu SGBD. A mais abrangente seria algo assim:

```
SELECT
    user.id_user,
    user.type,
    (
        CASE user.type
            WHEN 1 THEN store.company_name
            WHEN 2 THEN service_provider.name
        END
    ) AS name
FROM
    user
    LEFT JOIN store ON user.id_user = store.id_user AND user.type = 1
    LEFT JOIN service_provider ON user.id_user = service_provider.id_user AND user.type = 2
```

**Explicando:**

Selecionamos todos registros de user fazendo `LEFT JOIN` com ambas as tabelas filtrando pelo tipo, com isso teremos o `JOIN` com sucesso para o registro que existir. E no `SELECT` fazemos um `CASE` para identificar e retornar o valor da tabela/campo conforme o tipo.

Comment: fiz algumas mudanças na parte do JOIN, ficou assim `INNER JOIN store ON store.id_user = user.id_user
    INNER JOIN service_provider ON service_provider.id_user = user.id_user WHERE user.id_user = 23`. Removi a parte do user.type = x, pois como a chave primária das entidades especializadas também fazem parte da chave estrangeira da entidade genérica, se houver um id_user = 10 em uma entidade especializada por exemplo, esse id não irá aparecer na outra especialização. Porém ainda sim não está retornando os _records_ corretos, naverdade, não está retornando nada.

Comment: Se ou você tem uma especialização ou a outra, mas não ambas simultaneamente, então certamente o INNER JOIN que você modificou retornará zero ocorrências. Por isso é que Diego Marques utilizou LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Sim sim, aparentemente interpretei errado o uso dos JOINS em uma recuperação de dados, o LEFT JOIN sempre retornará o valor da tabela a esquerda mesmo se não houver chave estrangeira correspondente, mas para resolver isso é só colocar uma clausula WHERE no final. Cometi alguns erros de interpretação, ainda estou me aprofundando no SQL...